# How to include old Javascript files into new Wordpress site redesign

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am going to redesign an existing site and will be using Wordpress. The current site is on a different CMS. There are a lot of Javascript slideshow type files in the current site and it would take a long to time to recreate all the files.

Is it fairly easy to add the js files inside a template? Do you just add them like you normally would?

Comment: Just include the `<script>` tag, not the code (although you'll want a local copy of the code file to prevent unwanted/unexpected changes to the code. See here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Javascript

Answer (score 0):

WordPress provides a better (recommended) way to add `scripts` using [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) function, for example, the following code (paste in your `functions.php` file) will add a `my_custom_script.js` file from `yourThemeDirectory/js/` folder

```
function add_my_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'custom-script',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/my_custom_script.js',
        array( 'jquery' )
    );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_script' );
```

In this given example, the first argument is the `handle/name` for your script, second parameter is the full path with file name that you want to add and the third parameter is the script dependency and in this case WordPress will require for `jQuery` to be loaded before your `my_custom_script.js` loads.

To load the `jQuery` simply you can use `wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' )` with `add_action`, because in `WordPress` some libraries are registered by default (including jQuery). Read the documentation for more details.

Comment: thanks so much. I am just doing all my homework before making the jump to wordpress to make sure I can keep some elements of the existing site.